# Drive.Files.get() not working. Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, file-not-found

Trying to open a file from the file ID using Drive.Files.get(). Doing:

```
afile = Drive.Files.get({
  fileID: "1LyhjPE2sQKaVJQGah_10ik_PnD5q5n6P0QlwD_XWZWc",
  supportAllDrives: true 
});
```

I get a file not found exception:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with
> error: File not found:
> supportAllDrives,true,fileID,1LyhjPE2sQKaVJQGah_10ik_PnD5q5n6P0QlwD_XWZWc

The file exists and can be opened. The sharing URL is (don't worry it's a blank text file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LyhjPE2sQKaVJQGah_10ik_PnD5q5n6P0QlwD_XWZWc/edit?usp=sharing

I'm probably missing something dumb here, but I've been banging my head against this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try ``fileId``(`d` in lowercase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of "Method: files.get" of Drive API at Advanced Google service of Google Apps Script, it seems that the arguments of `Drive.Files.get(fileId: string, optionalArgs: Object)` are `fileId: string` and `optionalArgs: Object`. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
afile = Drive.Files.get("1LyhjPE2sQKaVJQGah_10ik_PnD5q5n6P0QlwD_XWZWc", { supportAllDrives: true });
```

- If the file ID of your `1LyhjPE2sQKaVJQGah_10ik_PnD5q5n6P0QlwD_XWZWc` is valid file ID and Drive API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services, this script is run, the file metadata is returned.
- This report might be useful. [Ref (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86)

#### References:

- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/get)
- [Taking Advantage of Auto-completion of Script Editor for Google Apps Script](https://medium.com/google-cloud/taking-advantage-of-auto-completion-of-script-editor-for-google-apps-script-be088a76cd86)

Comment: That's it. As always, I am grateful Tanaike.